# Binding nested UserControls to properties exposed in the ViewModel

Tags: wpf

I have a UserControl that has an image on it. It has it's Visibility property bound to a property (named "On") on the ViewModel (which raises a PropertyChanged event). Now I'd like to create another UserControl which contains a few of these UserControls. It will have its own ViewModel which will expose another set of properties that should effect these image UserControls.

I could just use FindName and explicitly grab their view model and set the On property, but I was wondering if there was a way to handle this through binding, ex.

```
<local:MyImageView x:Name="MyImage1" On="{Binding Image1On}" />
```

Where Image1On would be another property on the second UserControl's ViewModel.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would usually handle this is by having the new view model you are talking about contain instances of your original view models with the "On" property.  (Whether it is a direct property or a collection of them depends on the situation)  Then instead of dealing with the UI elements, you are just dealing with the properties of your view models.

For example:  "Room" view model contains a Collection of "Light" view models.

```
public class RoomViewModel
{
   LightViewModel frontLights
   {
      //implementation
   }
   LightViewModel rearLights
   { 
     //implementation
   }

   // Create a ICommand Implementation around this
   public void ToggleFrontLights(bool turnLightsOn)
   {
      frontLights.On = turnLightsOn;
   }}
```